# XE8 TWebBrowser (64bit) on iOS shows black borders after zoom out

Tags: ios, delphi, 64-bit, twebbrowser

I am trying to show some local HTML files on iOS using the TWebBrowser component of XE8. I noticed that when you zoom out the webview, then the 64bit iOS version shows black borders instead of the usual gray background. These black borders don't go away anymore until I restart the App. The same App compiled for 32bit works fine. 
This can simply be reproduced by putting a TWebBrowser component on a blank form and running this on iOS.
Does anybody have a fix for this annoying bug ?

Comment: It seems like a bug of the component in that specific architecture, you should open a case on Embarcadero Quality Central .

Comment: Yes definitely, I will do that, but I hope that somebody already has found a quick fix for this annoying behavior